# Vue: how to animate reordering of a list?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a bunch of posts and each post has a score.  I want to have the posts rearrange based on the posts score. The scores are updated via websockets so if the `Post` at the top has a `score` of 40 and gets rapidly downvoted, how would I animate that to have that to the bottom of the screen rather than moving it one at a time?

Comment: Use [`transition-group`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions): the documentation contains good examples on animating elements. Your posts should probably come from a computer property that returns an array sorted based on vote count.

Comment: awesome, thanks Terry